# C# / WPF Databinding and backgroundworkers

Tags: wpf, multithreading, xaml, data-binding, backgroundworker

**Update2**

*I've rewritten the entire question, because some things became a lot clearer, the issue now seems to be that I created a list of DependencyProperties on a different thread than where the DependencyProperties will be used :(.*

When I do some work on a `BackgroundWorker` the `XAML` bindings cause an `ArgumentException`

> > Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject.

I've got the following setup:

I've got a simple class that implements  `INotifyPropertyChanged` which contains a few ints, list's and Dictionaries.

```
public class Calculator : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //Note that InstanceGroup is a dependency object
    private List<InstanceGroup> instanceGroups = new List<InstanceGroup>();
    public List<InstanceGroup> InstanceGroups
    {
        get { return instanceGroups; }
        set { instanceGroups = value; }
    }

    // snip //

    public void Calculate()
    {
        InstanceGroups = MyNewFilledInstanceGroup;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
              PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("instanceGroups"));
            }
    }
}
```

In a `UserControl` I use a `BackgroundWorker` to run the `Calculate` method, because it can take a lot of time:

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += delegate(object o, DoWorkEventArgs args)
{
    lock (Calculator)
    {       
        Calculator.Calculate();
    }
};
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

In the `XAML` file of the `UserControl` I have multiple bindings to the `Calculator`, like `{Binding Path=Calculator.InstanceGroups, Path=userControlName}`.

(The overall goal is to be able to do all the work in the Calculate method on a separate thread so I can show a progress bar or something like that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution seems to be to not create DependencyProperties ( [How to handle ObservableCollection<> result from a parallelized Task in MVVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625581/how-to-handle-observablecollection-result-from-a-parallelized-task-in-mvvm) ) in a background task, this weird behavior costed me the better part of the day. But at least now I know what the problem was.

Answer (score 2):

I am not convinced that you need to use DP for this Observable collection. Best to store it in ViewModel.

ObservableCollections are not thread-safe, and you need to use Dispatcher to update the collection.

Google there were some posts with Extension to ObservableCollection which used Dispatcher.

[This link might help](http://deanchalk.com/2010/02/01/thread-safe-dispatcher-safe-observable-collection-for-wpf/)

Comment: Hey Anvarbek, I've (temporarily) replaced the ObservableCollection with a normal List<> but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Any `DependencyObject` includes a `Dispatcher` property that can help you push work to the correct thread for that object.

You can use `Dispatcher.Invoke` or `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` to run code on the correct thread.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness I'd mention two solutions of WPF guru [Dean Chalk](http://deanchalk.com):

1. Create a thread-safe observable collection. It's an old school solution that just works. To get the source code check a [short article in his blog](http://deanchalk.com/2010/02/01/thread-safe-dispatcher-safe-observable-collection-for-wpf/). This one was mentioned by anvarbek raupov in this thread earlier. Similar solution is in [Sasha Barber's blog](http://sachabarbs.wordpress.com/2009/01/31/threadsafeobservablecollectiont/).
2. Use [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) library. See [this article](http://deanchalk.com/2013/05/16/multi-threading-observablecollection-reactive-extensions/) for an example. It's a bit bulky for one task, but meanwhile it brings a bunch of modern tools what come in handy.